# How can I mount "sub-controllers" in silex

Tags: php, controller, silex

So I'm working on a Silex project that is a checkbook register. The idea is that accounts have transactions. I am using the approach of having controller providers, so I am mounting the providers. It's clear to me that I can just mount /accounts and /transactions for the respective controller providers. Since logically transactions are children of accounts, however, I was hoping to achieve this type of URL structure:

`/account/1` = get request for account ID 1

`/account/1/transaction/100` = get request for transaction ID 100, including account ID 1 as a parameter

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I failed to mention that my controller setup looks as such:

bootstrap.php:

```
$app->mount('/account', new AccountControllerProvider());
$app->mount('/transaction', new TransactionControllerProvider());
```

AccountControllerProvider.php:

```
$controllers->put('/', 'Mogaard\Checkbook\Controller\AccountController::createAction')
    ->bind('account_create');
$controllers->get('/{account}', 'Mogaard\Checkbook\Controller\AccountController::displayAction')
    ->convert('account', $accountProvider)
    ->bind('account_display');
$controllers->post('/{account}', 'Mogaard\Checkbook\Controller\AccountController::saveAction')
    ->convert('account', $accountProvider)
    ->bind('account_save');
$controllers->delete('/{account}', 'Mogaard\Checkbook\Controller\AccountController::deleteAction')
    ->convert('account', $accountProvider)
    ->bind('account_delete');
```

TransactionControllerProvider.php:

```
$controllers->put('/', 'Mogaard\Checkbook\Controller\TransactionController::createAction')
    ->bind('transaction_create');
$controllers->post('/{transaction}', 'Mogaard\Checkbook\Controller\TransactionController::saveAction')
    ->convert('transaction', $transactionProvider)
    ->bind('transaction_save');
$controllers->delete('/{transaction}', 'Mogaard\Checkbook\Controller\TransactionController::deleteAction')
    ->convert('transaction', $transactionProvider)
    ->bind('transaction_delete');
```

I am looking to add a route for /account/{account}/transaction/{transaction}, but I am unsure of how to do it using mounted controller providers and without mixing transaction controller responsibilities into the account controller provider.

Comment: I may not be too used to silex, but have you tried `$app->get('/account/{accId}/transaction/{transId}'...)`?

Comment: @Korcholis You should post this as an answer. ;-)

Comment: @Igorw this is a little awkward to repost this but anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Igorw, I'll just post this as an answer (just in case the poster didn't read the comment):

I may not be too used to silex, but have you tried

`$app->get('/account/{accId}/transaction/{transId}'...)`?

**Edit:**

Once you have that route traced, you could just [forward](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#forwards) `/account/{accId}/transaction/{transId}` to `/transaction/account/$accId/transaction/$transId`. It will be invisible to the user, just as an `.htaccess` would do. Or even use an `.htaccess` to map these routes to the one that fits you best.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I have my account controller provider mounted at /account and my transaction controller provider mounted at /transaction. I apologize, because I failed to mention this in the original question. I will add it. So the issue with this proposed solution is that if I try to use /account/{accId}/transaction/{transId}, it will be prepended with /transaction because I've mounted the provider to that route branch, resulting in /transaction/account/{accId}/transaction/{transId}. Thank you for the suggestion, though.

Comment: You could just [forward](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#forwards) `/account/{accId}/transaction/{transId}` to `/transaction/account/$accId/transaction/$transId`. It will be invisible to the user, just as an .htaccess would do. Or even use an .htaccess to map these routes to the one that fits you best.

Comment: Ahhh, yes. I believe the forward will work for me here. I can't believe I missed this in the Silex documentation. Sorry to waste your guys' time. Thanks very much for the help. Korcholis, if you edit your answer with this or post a new one I'll mark it as accepted so you can get credit. Thanks again.

Comment: Your wish is my command. Don't worry about that. You can check my last questions and you'll see all the silex related are answered within the docs. As I say there, the silex documentation is not as clear as it should. I'm glad I could help you =)